# angularjs - dynamic ng-models

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
<!---->
 <div ng-repeat="priority in toppriorities">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>{{priority}}.</td>
    <td>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="APME" ng-change="changedValue(APME,priority)" >
         <option ng-repeat="me in mainelements" value="{{me.Recomendation}}">{{me.Title}}</option>
        </select>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div ng-model="APMER[priority]">{{APMER[priority]}}</div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

I want to update ``` ng-model``APMER[priority] ``` to be updated after I selected something from `APME`:

```
//JS
$scope.changedValue=function(i, priority){
        $scope.APMER[priority] = i;
    }
```

1. I somehow cannot get `ng-model="APMER[priority]"` to work.
2. in `js` - `ng-model="APMER[priority]"`, What is the proper way to assign dynamic variable?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like this.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="QuestionController">
    <ul ng-repeat="question in Questions">
        <li>
            <div>{{question.Text}}</div>
            <select ng-model="Answers[question.Name]" ng-options="option for option in question.Options">
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <a ng-click="ShowAnswers()">Submit</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DrQ77/

That will allow you to put a javascript expression within a model.